# how do you make form.submit() work in firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, dom

I've implemented the following code:

```
function post(path, params) {

    var form = document.createElement('form');
    form.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
    form.setAttribute('action', path);

    var hiddenField = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'JSON');
    hiddenField.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
    hiddenField.setAttribute('value', JSON.stringify(params));

    form.appendChild(hiddenField);

    form.submit();

}
```

It works wonderfully in chrome, safari, and IE but does nothing when using firefox.

any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: Does the console show an error?

Comment: @JohnConde no, just does nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try add

```
document.body.appendChild(form)
```

beforesubmit

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the form in the DOM of the page before Firefox will submit it.

```
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```

… should do the trick.